# What is the cleanest way for validation on dynamic forms in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, web, django-forms

I have been working on a project for an online clothes, shoes, accessories store for a while. I have a form with category, subcategory, size field etc. If the selected category is either "clothes" or "shoes" the size field is required. But if the category choice is "accessories" the size field is hidden and it's not required, because in my case accessories don't have sizes. Also my category choices are not hard coded, they are stored in the database. So while I was doing the validation, in my form's clean method I hard coded an if statement which fires an error when the user's category choice is different from "accessories" and when the size field is blank. But I think that this is not very clean, because the if statement is kinda hard coded. And my question is: Is it there any cleaner solution to do this task?

```
class ItemCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['category', 'subcategory', 'brand', 'brand_collection', 'price', 'price_negotiable',
                  'size', 'gender', 'condition', 'description']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        category = cleaned_data.get("category")
        size = cleaned_data.get("size")

        if str(category) != 'accessories' and not size:
            print(category)
            print(size)
            self.add_error('size', 'Това поле е задължително!')

        return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

If that data is in the database, you'll probably need to keep the condition logic in the database too. You could come up with a domain-specific language of your own and shove a "program" in your Category model in a text field - contrived example that probably misses something:

```
ifempty size error "Това поле е задължително!"
iflt size 0 error "Size must be >= 0"
ifgt size 50 error "Size must be <= 50"
```

It would be fairly straightforward to write an interpreter for something like that... Or if you're feeling more adventurous, maybe something S-expression based? I would advise against saving straight-up Python there, though, since it's hard to sandbox.